# Filter number from Array of string and get the index of last two greater number in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a ArrayList that has value like [Value,Sum3,121,data8input,in:21::7,7.00,9.01] and I want to extract only number  as the output should be like this [3,121,8,21,7,7.00,9.01] and then have to rearrange ascending and then get the index of last two number as result will be [21,121].

My tried code below,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.size(); i++) {
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(,\\d+)*?\\.?\\d+?");
                    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(arrayString.get(i).getvalue);
                   numbers.addAll(m);
                    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
                            Log.d("REMEMBERFILTER", allCollection.get(i).getTextValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

**do something like this, though it is not exactly memory efficient as I am using another list.**

```
ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.size(); i++) {
                tempList.add(yourArrayList.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
            }

    //Arrange in ascending order
  Collections.sort(tempList);
//Also try to remove those indexes which has only letters with
    tempList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("+++++++++", "" + tempList.get(i));
            }
//You can get the last two or any element by get method of list by //list.size()-1 and list.size()-2 so on
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to  do it, `finalArray` has the 2 numbers you want:

```
    String[] str = new String[] {"Value", "Sum3", "121", "data8input", "in:21::7", "7.00,9.01"};

    StringBuilder longStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String s : str) {
        longStringBuilder.append(s).append(" ");
    }

    String longString = longStringBuilder.toString();

    String onlyNumbers = " " + longString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", " ") + " ";
    onlyNumbers = onlyNumbers.replaceAll(" \\. ", "").trim();

    while (onlyNumbers.indexOf("  ") > 0) {
        onlyNumbers = onlyNumbers.replaceAll("  ", " ");
    }

    String[] array = onlyNumbers.split(" ");
    Double[] doubleArray = new Double[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        try {
            doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            doubleArray[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(doubleArray);

    int numbersCount = doubleArray.length;

    Double[] finalArray;
    if (numbersCount >= 2) {
        finalArray = new Double[]{doubleArray[numbersCount - 2], doubleArray[numbersCount - 1]};
    } else if (numbersCount == 1) {
        finalArray = new Double[]{ doubleArray[0]};
    } else {
        finalArray = new Double[]{};
    }

    for (Double number : finalArray) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```